# Implementing a typedef function from a header into a source file in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, typedef

I'm trying to implement a hash function for a HashMap class currently. We were given a HashMap.h file and we can not change any of the pre-defined member variables and functions. This hasn't proved to be a challenge when implementing my .cpp file for the HashMap class, until I got to this line:

```
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
```

Normally if this was in my header file:

```
HashMap();
```

I could do this in my source file to implement it:

```
HashMap::HashMap() {
// code here
}
```

My question is how do I implement this typedef in my source file? I have my hash function (hashFunc) that takes in a const string, and returns an unsigned int, like so:

```
HashMap::hashFunc(const std::string& key)
{
    unsigned int hashValue = 0; // what we end up returning
    // hashFunc code here
    return hashValue;
}
```

But since I have to use this hash function in constructors, copiers, and more within my source file, I am supposed to declare it from this typedef. For example, like:

```
HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hashFunc) { }
```

How can I make this work? I've tried things like HashFunction HashMap::hashFunc(), HashMap::HashFunction hashFunc(), and HashMap::HashFunction::hashFunc(), but nothing works :( I'm new to C++ so I realize I probably look dumb right now with this question, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a typedef"? It's just an alias for a type.

Comment: I just meant put it in my class source file. Since HashFunction HashMap::hashFunc(const std::string& key) { // code } doesn't compile, while something like int HashMap::hashFunc(const std::string& key) { // code } would.

Comment: If the answer I posted is not sufficient, it might be helpful if you appended the contents of HashMap.h to the end of your question so we can see exactly what constraints you're working under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have realized, `std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)>` is the type of a function taking a string in input and returning an `unsigned int`, to be used as an hash function for the map.

That `typedef` allows you to identify *"any function taking a string and returning an unsigned"*. At this point,`HashFunction` is just a type, like `int` or `string` is.

The constructor of `HashMap` could have a parameter of type `HashFunction` to specify the hash function, like:

```
class HashMap {
public:
    explicit HashMap(const HashFunction &h): hash(h) {}
    //...
    void put(std::string element) {
        unsigned int h = hash(element);
        //...
    }
    //...
private:
    HashFunction hash;
}
```

As you can see, I have declared a variable `hash`, of type `HashFunction` which *is* a function you can call in the `HashMap::put` method.

At this point you might wonder how you can create something whose type is `HashFunction`. Well, the simplest answer is: by defining a "standard" function whose signature match the one of a `HashFunction`. For instance, here is a DJB hash:

```
unsigned int DJB_hash(const std::string &s) {
    unsigned int h = 5318;

    for (char c: s) {
        h = 33 * h + c;
    }

    return h;
}
```

Or, before C++11:

```
unsigned int DJB_hash(const std::string &s) {
    unsigned int h = 5318;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        h = 33 * h + s[i];
    }

    return h;
}
```

Now you can construct the hashmap with:

```
HashMap map(DJB_hash);
```

Comment: I will add this as a comment because I don't want you to make confusion: if you have a C background, you might see that a `std::function` variable bears some resemblance to a function pointer in C.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a typedef. There's nothing to implement.

```
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
```

The line says that there's a type `std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)>` and that from now on you can refer to that type under the `HashFunction` alias. `std::function` is just a wrapper around something that's [Callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) such as functions, lambdas, functors and others. Imagine you have a function taking a `HashFunction` argument and immediately invokes it.

```
void foo(HashFunction func)
{
    unsigned int hashed_string = func("hello");
}
```

As mentioned, there're several ways of calling the `foo` function.

```
unsigned int my_hash_func(const std::string& key)
{
  // do something with key
  return 42;
}

// With function pointer
foo(&my_hash_func);

// With lambda
foo([](const std::string& key) {
    // do something with key
    return 42;
});
```

The same applies when you have a class and its constructor takes `HashFunction`.

```
class HashMap
{
  HashFunction hash_func_;

public:
  HashMap(HashFunction hash_func) : hash_func_(hash_func)
  {}
};


HashMap m(&my_hash_func);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the purpose of this exercise is to make a class more "generic" by
defining some of the class's function code *outside* of the class.

Consider this function (note the declared return value *has* to match the thing
you end up returning):

```
unsigned int HashMap::hashFunc(const std::string& key)
{
    unsigned int hashValue = 0; // what we end up returning
    // hashFunc code here
    return hashValue;
}
```

If you were implementing `HashMap` without using `std::function`,
you might just replace `// hashFunc code here` with a few lines of code,
for example

```
    hashValue = static_cast<unsigned int>(key[0]);
```

which is a horrible hash function, but it illustrates the point, which is that
the function `HashMap::hashFunc` has a very predetermined way to compute hashes.
You can never compute the hash any differently whenever you use `HashMap`.

So instead of some lines of code that always hash the key exactly the same way,
you're supposed to replace `// hashFunc code here` with a use of a *lambda*
that was previously passed into your `HashMap` constructor and stored by it.
This way, instead of being defined when you write the code of `HashMap` itself,
the function that hashes strings is determined when you construct an
instance of `HashMap`.

So you need to store a lambda (presumably as a member of `HashMap`)
and you need to use it when you hash keys in `HashMap`.

Since it is often easier to learn by example than by abstract definitions,
here's a toy program (tested at http://ideone.com/) that prints the number 17
in a tremendously overcomplicated way:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<int(int)> Transformation;

class Something
{
public:
  Something(Transformation transformation_in, int value_in)
    : transform(transformation_in)
  {
    int value_out = transform(value_in);
    std::cout << value_out << std::endl;
  }

private:
  Transformation transform;
};

Transformation increment_by_one = [](int value_in){ return value_in + 1; };

int main() {
  Something something(increment_by_one, 16);
  return 0;
}
```

In this code the lambda is used in the constructor, but of course it can
be used later in another function of the class since it is stored as a class member.
The point is that the class `Something` doesn't "know" how to compute
the printed value from the input integer `value_in` until the instance of `Something`
is actually constructed.